# how to load assets in ejs file when you have two different main routes?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, assets

i have simple blog express app which i set up of two different main routes, regular routes (login,post,signup etc...) and for admin (add post,edit post etc...) the issue is my assets, css or any other static files does not load in the **admin routes** only but fortunately works in regular routes. my express setup is as follow:

```
app.use('/admin/pages', adminPages);
app.use('/', pages);
```

so after investigating the chrome developer tools for both main routs this is the issue but have no idea how to solve it ! 
this is when the admin routs does not load bootstrap or css files:
[image]
notice all assets is prefixed with unwanted (admin/pages/...) after localhost:3005

but it works here (without the prefix) :
[image]

heres my file structure:

[image]

full App.js :

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    pages = require('./routes/pages.js'),
    config = require('./config/database'),
    expressSession = require('express-session'),
    expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
    adminPages = require('./routes/admin_pages.js');

mongoose.connect(config.database);
const database = mongoose.connection;
database.on('error', console.error.bind(console, '@@error with database:'));
database.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connected To Database successfully');
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(
    expressSession({
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { secure: true }
    })
);

app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
    next();
});

app.use(
    expressValidator({
        errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
            var namespace = param.split('.'),
                root = namespace.shift(),
                formParam = root;
            while (namespace.length) {
                formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
            }
            return {
                param: formParam,
                msg: msg,
                value: value
            };
        }
    })
);

app.use('/admin/pages', adminPages);
app.use('/', pages);

const port = 3005;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App Listening @ localhost:${port}`);
});
```

add_page.ejs :

```
<%- include('../_layouts/header') %>

    <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <button> submit </button>
    </form>
    <%- include('../_layouts/footer') %>
```

heres my both main routes:
[image]

Comment: Could you share your views files?

Comment: @vitomadio i have already updated the post with image of my file structure. tks

Comment: I suppose you have your styles links inside the header-admin.ejs layout, right? then you import this partial inside the add_page.ejs, correct me if am wrong.

Comment: yes exactly, header and header-admin very similar but with few extra links. it works for index.ejs when using the partials but not the add_page.ejs

Comment: Try getting out add_pages.ejs from admin folder, putting it in the same root of index.ejs

Comment: same thing happens, i tried to put it in the same location as index but it didn't work

Comment: Could you share your add_page code at least, because this way is very hard to understand what could be happening.

Comment: i have updated the post with App.js file source code almost 70 lines !

Comment: done, i added the add_page.ejs

Comment: Ok, in your app.js seems everything is fine, but in your add_pages.ejs, why you didn't include header_admin.ejs?

Comment: its the same thing i tested for both header_admin.ejs and header.ejs though it might work both has same links to bootstrap and css

Comment: i have added both routes structures might help solve the problem

Comment: Try doing your include like this <%- include _layouts/header.ejs %>, if it doesn't work I don't know what else could it be, since can't find anything wrong in your code bro.

Comment: thanks  a lot bro appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've found the answer.
when using two main routes you need to specify each route to its static file so we have got this middleware for the regular route as follow :

```
app.use('/', express.static('public'));
```

since you have another route for admin/pages this was missing:

```
app.use('/admin/pages', express.static('public'));
```

this fixed the issue :D

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using only one main route, so I changed the asset url adding a `/` at the beginning of the url and it work for me:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
```

Maybe it can be helpful for someone else, regards!